# Burninate [elixir-framework]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

[elixir-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir-framework) is a vague and pointless tag. There are currently 145 questions with this tag. Its excerpt is:

> Frameworks for Elixir like Dynamo and Phoenix, that leverage the power of the Erlang VM to build high performance and concurrent web applications.

[elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir) is a programming language. Dynamo and Phoenix are specific frameworks which should have their own tags. Phoenix does (see [phoenix-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework)), Dynamo currently doesn't but only has 5 related questions, none of which are even tagged with [elixir-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir-framework) (see the query ["[elixir] dynamo"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belixir%5D+dynamo)).

#### Burnination criteria

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. It's essentially an umbrella tag for an unspecified set of "frameworks".

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

As it doesn't describe any specific concept, I'd say no.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it should be covered entirely by tags for the language and specific framework.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. I'm not even sure it means *anything* in *any* context. It could refer to a number of different frameworks depending on context, or something else entirely depending on the interpretation of "framework".

**5. Does it cause harm?**

It is at best pointless, at worst confusingly vague and used in place of more appropriate tags.

[Example of a question using [elixir-framework] instead of [phoenix-framework]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477299/convert-struct-to-list-in-elixir)

[Example of a question using [elixir-framework] without mention of any kind of specific framework in the tags or in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62022990/how-do-i-implement-a-string-protocol-for-an-array-of-custom-type-in-elixir)

Comment: 146 question with a lot of answers. looks quite like any other tag that is active, with no that much traffic,

Comment: What would probably work better is a merge. Only 7 questions in this tag are not also tagged [elixir]. No burn necessary

Comment: @Machavity Ah, yes, I thought that would be a kind of burn, but I see now it's considered a retag. Should I submit a separate retag-request? Or alter this to include retag-request and mention merging as an option?

Comment: I may agree with the burn, but I don't think it satisfies any of the criteria. All your "No"s seem twisted to somehow satisfy the criteria. On that note, Do anyone else consider the burninate criteria impossible to satisfy for most valid cases?

Comment: @TheMaster I think it's pretty clearly ambiguous and not adding meaningful information. And I find it hard to see how an ambiguous tag could mean the same thing in all common contexts, but I think that criteria is pretty vague too. Finally, I find it hard to determine whether it's on-topic when the meaning of the tag is so vague, so I've basically defaulted to answering "No" if I can't definitively answer "Yes'.

Comment: Due to the low number of questions ultimately impacted, I went ahead and merged them